# How to group objects from angular http call to backend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am calling the backend with this http call:

```
this.StudentEnrollment.getRecordsById(list.value.split(/[\r\n]+/)).subscribe(values => {
  this.studentObject = values;
});
```

studenObject looks like this

```
{
    records: [{name: james, school: USC, .....}, {name: Micheal, school: UCLA, ......},{name: 
         John, school: UCLA, ......}],
    size: 3
}
```

Is it possible to group the schools and add a count then add it to studentObject? So object could look something like this:

```
[{school: UCLA, count: 2}, {school: USC, count: 1}]
```

Comment: RxJS has a groupBy operator as shown here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/groupBy. I cover it in my talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPy35fOjRyU It's the third technique that I cover in this talk, starting about 15 min in.

Answer (score 2):

Using the groupBy operator, you could do something like this:

```
data$ = this.StudentEnrollment.getRecordsById(list.value.split(/[\r\n]+/));

schoolsGrouped$ = data$.pipe(
     // Use concatMap to emit the array elements one by one for the groupBy
     concatMap(students => students),
     // Group by the student's school
     groupBy(student => student.school),
     // Merge each grouped set
     mergeMap(group =>
       zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())).pipe(
         map(([key, students]) => ({ key, students }))
       )
     ),
     // Emit one array of the grouped results
     toArray()
   );
```

You could then access the data like this:

```
  constructor() {
    this.schoolsGrouped$.subscribe(schools => 
      schools.forEach(school => console.log(school.key, school.students.length)))
  }
```

There is a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-schools-groupby-deborahk

To add the grouped info to the existing data structure, you can do something like this (see the added `tap` operator:

```
  schoolsGrouped$ = of(this.data.records).pipe(
    // Emit the array elements one by one for the groupBy
    concatMap(students => students),
    groupBy(student => student.school),
    // Merge each grouped set
    mergeMap(group =>
      zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())).pipe(
        map(([key, students]) => ({ key, students }))
      )
    ),
    // Add the result to the existing data object
    tap(
      school =>
        (this.data = {
          ...this.data,
          schools: [
            ...this.data.schools,
            { school: school.key, count: school.students.length },
          ],
        })
    ),
    // Emit one array of the grouped results
    toArray()
  );
```

Comment: I have a code review at [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275211/if-condition-in-combinelatest-observables](here). I can't figure it out. Could you please help me out?